# M2 - Dutch date format

Tags: magento2, language, date, translate

I'm using Magento 2.3.1 and I've installed the Dutch language pack. But the date stays in English like: 08 May 2019 instead of 8 Mei 2019. How can this be changed?

The code:

```
<?php echo date('d M Y', strtotime($post->getCreatedAt())) ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not sure would this work

```
$locale = 'nl_NL';
$date = new Zend_Date($_product->getData('delivery_eta'));
$date->setLocale($locale);
echo $date->toString(Zend_Date::DATE_LONG);
```